# Can I change /home partition to /boot?

Tags: arch-linux, partition, dual-boot

When installing Arch I did (or I though at least) a /, swap and a /boot partition.

I just found out that I have a /, swap and /home partition. Which isn't what I had in mind, I just have like 400mb for the /boot partition, but since is a /home partition it's like I won't have any space.

Can I change that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure—partitions are mounted wherever you specify in `/etc/fstab`. It appears you don't actually need a /boot partition (since your machine is booting without one); you could just leave it unused:

1. Log out, log in as root on the console. This is so your home directory is not in use.
2. Just to make sure nothing is using it, `umount /home`. If that fails, use things like `fuser -vm /home` and `lsof /home` to find out what's still open, close/kill them, and try again. Once it finally unmounts, then go ahead and `mount /home` again.
3. `mv`/`cp -a` everything out of `/home` (on the 400mb partition) to somewhere else. Take note of the permissions of `/home` itself.
4. `umount /home`
5. Fix the permissions on `/home`. Then move everything from its temporary location to `/home` (on rootfs).
6. Edit `/etc/fstab` to no longer mount that filesystem on `/home`. You could, for example, just comment out the line.

You could do similar thing for the stuff currently in /boot and moving it to the 400mb filesystem—but you'll also need to update your bootloader config, maybe reinstall it, etc. Much more likely to cause your system not to boot. If you're using lvm, I'd just `lvremove` the 400MB LV. Otherwise... if it's 400MB out of several TB, I'd ignore it. Or repurpose it for something else. It may have a label on it saying 'home' or similar; you can check (and change it) with `e2label /dev/whatever`.

Comment: I see, but before trying that out... My /home partition is bootable. I just happened to make a /home partition instead of /boot, don't even know how. My current partition schema is: /, swap and /home, but before finding that out I thought I have: /, swap and /boot. 

Should I follow the same instructions then?

Comment: @ericgramirez You mean it's set bootable in the partition table? I presume you somehow set it up as /home in the Arch installer (not personally familiar with Arch, so I'm not sure exactly how the installer asks for filesystems). As long as it only has /home contents on it, it should be safe to move that back on to the rootfs. Destroying the fs (e.g., with lvremove) I guess has a small chance of making you need a recovery disk to get your system to boot again.

Comment: @ericgramirez also, depending on how Arch does it, you may need to regenerate the initramfs.

Comment: I see. I must admit I'm just starting out on Linux and that I didn't quite understad the lastest comments. Would you please explain it with more details or refer me to some guide (so we can be on the same page)?

Comment: @ericgramirez Ok... I upvoted your question, now you have enough rep to use [chat]. Ping me in [the site's chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux) and I'll try to explain.

Comment: @ericgramirez and to be clear, you ping someone in chat (or in comments) by typing `@` and then his/her user name (should autocomplete for you). So `@derobert` would ping me.